# How many different square roots can you find of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say I have an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$

And I want to find a matrix $B$ such that $BB = A$. How can I find the total number of possible $B$'s that satisfy this condition?

What I was thinking of, was set up a system of equations to solve for each entry $a_{ij}$ in terms of $b_{ij}$, via dot-products, like so:

$$\begin{align}a_{11} &= {b_{11}}^2 + b_{12}\cdot b_{21} \\
a_{12} &= b_{11} \cdot b_{12} + b_{12}\cdot b_{22} \\
a_{21} &= b_{11} \cdot b_{21} + b_{22}\cdot b_{21} \\
a_{22} &=  b_{21}\cdot b_{12} + {b_{22}}^2
\end{align}$$

But as you can see this is not a linear system of equations, and there's no method I currently know of to solve for the unknowns in this system, other than simply guessing and playing around to see which values could work.

And this only a $2 \times 2$ matrix, it would be impossible to find out this way how many square roots exist for a $n \times n$ matrix.

So my question is: How many square roots exist for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and what method can be used to find all of those square roots?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable and has only non-negative eigenvalues, you can find such a matrix $B$.

Comment: Not sure, whether a matrix $B$ always exists (assuming that we are restricted to real entries).